# How to Access to first element within an object from each group in js with generated id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to access to the first element from every group of this object :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSqcS.png)

Comment: use Object.keys

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit  @AmruthLS

Comment: please attach some code, based on that i can guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact i needed to map each element and access to the first element like this :

```
   const groceries = Object.keys(this.props.groceries).map(key =>
    {
        return <Grocery product={this.props.groceries[key][0]} />

    });
```

Comment: you accepted your ans, great :) @RiHab

Answer (score 0):

It isn't totally clear what your request is here. If you are trying to do some task on each array value of the overall object key-value store you can do something like this:

```
const data = {
    guid1: [{ id: 'id1', foo: 'some value' }, { id: 'id11', foo: 'some value1' }],
    guid2: [],
    guid3: [{ id: 'id3', foo: 'some value3' }, { id: 'id33', foo: 'some value33' }],
};

// Get each array
console.log('-- Print all values of all array items');
for (const arr of Object.values(data)) {
    // Do something on each item of the array
    for (const item of arr) {
        console.log(`ID:${item.id} = ${item.foo}`)
    }
}

// OR
console.log('\n-- Print the first item of each array');
for (const arr of Object.values(data)) {
    // Do something on the first item in the array
    if (arr.length) {
        console.log(`ID:${arr[0].id} = ${arr[0].foo}`)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-- Print all values of all array items
ID:id1 = some value
ID:id11 = some value1
ID:id3 = some value3
ID:id33 = some value33

-- Print the first item of each array
ID:id1 = some value
ID:id3 = some value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through each keys in object and access value.
Here replace `obj` with your object name.

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key=>
  console.log(obj[key])//value
)
```

Comment: this answer seems the closest to what I am searching, the data is grouped by id and I need only to access the first element from each group.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array of objects and use:

```
Object.values(YourObjectGoesHere)[0]
//This only gets the value of the first element/key of the object
```

If you need the keys:

```
Object.keys(YourObjectGoesHere)
```

An approach could be:

```
let keys = Object.keys(YourObject)
let keyToCheck = "aKey"
if(keys.includes(keyToCheck) !== false){
  let keyValue = YourObject[keyToCheck]
  //...
}
```

Comment: i don't need the first element I need the first from each group. @Sebastian Borgers

Comment: Your question didn't really provide clear information on that, so I had to guess what you meant. However, even then, this is where the "loop over" would come into play.